# Create a new JSON array from nested key/values of existing JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

I have an array of Objects which will always be structured like so:

```
var initialJSON = [  
  {  
     "id":"01",
     "name":"Jane",
     "project":{  
        "title":"Alpha",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "city":"New York"
     },
     "dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:16 UTC"
   },
   {  
     "id":"02",
     "name":"Sarah",
     "project":{  
       "title":"Beta",
       "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
       "city":"London"
     },
      "dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:29 UTC"
    },
    {  
      "id":"03",
      "name":"Mia",
      "project":{  
         "title":"Gamma",
         "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
         "city":"Paris"
      },
      "dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:29 UTC"
   }
];
```

My goal is to create a new array of Objects containing just the key/values of each item's projects. Essentially removing all of the other data (including the parent key 'project') from each item.

The end result would look like so:

```
var formattedJSON = [
  {
    "title":"Alpha",
    "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "city":"New York"
  },
  {
    "title":"Beta",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "city":"London"
  },
  {
    "title":"Gamma",
    "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "Paris"
  }
]
```

I am having difficulty finding a way to loop through the data and achieve the correct result. I am aware there are similar questions already posted but non seem to create a new array out of the nested key/values of an inner key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this, by assigning each element of the array to it's `project` property:

```js
let initialJSON=[{"id":"01","name":"Jane","project":{"title":"Alpha","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","city":"New York"},"dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:16 UTC"},{"id":"02","name":"Sarah","project":{"title":"Beta","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","city":"London"},"dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:29 UTC"},{"id":"03","name":"Mia","project":{"title":"Gamma","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","city":"Paris"},"dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:29 UTC"}];

let result = initialJSON.map(element => element.project);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map` function on the `initialJSON` array to achieve this, in the following way:

```
var formattedJSON = initialJSON.map(item => {

  // For each item in the "initialJSON", map the fields to each item 
  // in the "formattedJSON" array
  return {
    title : item.project.title,
    description : item.project.description,
    city : item.project.city
  }

})
```

Comment: This is complicating things more than it should, `item.project` is already an Object, that you can return

Answer (score 0):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples) can be used to change or exlude values:

```js
var j = '[{"id":"01","name":"Jane","project":{"title":"Alpha","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","city":"New York"},"dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:16 UTC"},{"id":"02","name":"Sarah","project":{"title":"Beta","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","city":"London"},"dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:29 UTC"},{"id":"03","name":"Mia","project":{"title":"Gamma","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","city":"Paris"},"dateCreated":"2018-04-28 04:11:29 UTC"}]'

let result = JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => v.project || v);

console.log( result )
```